# How to fix Zone already loaded error in angular (my application needs to load angular multiple times)

Tags: javascript, angular, extjs, webpack

I have a module in angular 5 which is embedded in an application written in ext-js.

The application provides the flexibility to navigate between different modules. When the angular application is loaded for the first time, it works fine but when I navigate to angular again, I get the Zone already loaded error.

I have already tried the following things:

1. removed zone.js from script tag in the index.html file.
2. tried removing CommonChunksPlugin webpackJsonp conflict.(i used ng eject to get the webpack.config.js file and added custom output.jsonpFunction function.But the angular part of the application fails to load after that)

I am not comfortable with changing the build process(approach 2) at this stage as the application is very close to production.

Is there any other way I can fix this issue and what is the real cause of this issue?

Comment: Can someone share some insights on this issue?